# The adventures of Tom Sawyer sentence meaning

Tags: meaning

What does this phrase from The adventures of Tom Sawyer sentence mean:
"True, the knife would not cut anything, but it was a "sure-enough" Barlow, and there was inconceivable grandeur in that -- though where the Western boys ever got the idea that such a weapon could possibly **be counterfeited to its injury** is an imposing mystery and will always remain so, perhaps."

Thank you!

Comment: you want to know the meaning of those you have highlighted or all of it???

Answer (score 3):

The Barlow knife in question was an inexpensive and substandard knife<sup>1</sup>. The boys were very excited to have a genuine Barlow. However, a counterfeit Barlow could not possibly have been a worse knife; thus the knife could not have been "counterfeited to its injury".

<sup>1</sup> I assume Barlow also made better knives.

Comment: +1 The Barlow was a *style* of knife rather than a "brand", so a "sure-enough" Barlow is something of a oxymoron, though it appears that the boys of Hannibal did not recognize this. Its design put a premium on ruggedness and cheapness.

Answer (score 0):

The Barlow knife is a sharp and dangerous pocket knife.  A knife that "would not cut anything" could not be a "sure-enough" Barlow, no matter what the boys thought.  You can't "counterfeit" or fake the injury caused by the knife --or, in this case, the lack thereof.